# Binding new property on Custom Control to View Model

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, custom-controls, dependency-properties

How do i extend an existing control (ComboBox in my case) to include a new property which i can bind to a property on my view model??

I have a Dependancy Property on the control's class as follows:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(MyComboBox));

    public string MyText
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(MyComboBox.MyTextProperty).ToString();
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(MyComboBox.MyTextProperty, value);             
        }
    }
```

And want to bind to it declaratively from XAML like this:

```
<MyComboBox MyText="{Binding MyTextOnViewModel,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The Binding just won't work, any ideas why??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getter and setter reference TestTextProperty while the property is declared as MyTextProperty.

Your getter should also be casting instead of calling .ToString()

```
return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
```

See this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) for more complete instructions.

Comment: ok all good. thanks for the help man, but i had my custom control in a cell tamplate in a datagrid, which i forgot to mention.

Just changed the binding to {Binding DataContext.MyTextOnViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Pages:MyPage}}}